# About Kotlin code style. When do we use field?.let { it.doSomething() } and when use field?.doSomething() directly

Tags: kotlin

Recently I meet some problem about code style in Kotlin. I can't tell which code style is better.

Assume there are nullable field here:

```
var scoreView: TextView? = null
val bgImageView: ImageView? = null
```

And I'd like to write like:

```
fun foo() { 
    scoreView?.apply {
       text = getScore()
       textColor = getColor()
       ...
    }

    bgImageView?.apply {
        Glide.with(context)
             .load(xxx)
             .into(this)
    }
}
```

And my team leader want to change it to :

```
fun foo() {
    scoreView?.text = getScore()
    scoreView?.textColor = getColor()
    ...
    Glide.with(context)
         .load(xxx)
         .into(bgImageView?:return)
}
```

I feel both are ok to me, but prefer the first one because I could write less 'xxView?.'

I wonder if there is some code style or rule about this. Or some common view about it.

Thanks.

Comment: Your team leader should change it to `lateinit var` imo.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually xxView came from xml file by import kotlinx.xxx.view.*.  So in this case, it is better to use scoreView?.apply {} or scoreView?. doSomething() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Kotlin's [official coding style](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html), when you're calling multiple functions which primarily interact with one object, putting that code inside a scope function like `.apply` is the idiomatic approach. Of course, your workplace may use different conventions, so definitely ask your team leader about this.

In your first example, you're using `apply` for exactly the purpose it was designed: to set multiple properties on one object, and enhance readability in these situations.

```
scoreView?.apply {
   text = getScore()
   textColor = getColor()
   ...
}
```

In your second example, the `apply` function serves to separate code that acts on your nullable object `bgImageView`. This use is supported by the style guide, although it seems to recommend `let` more strongly in these nullable cases.

```
bgImageView?.apply { 
    Glide.with(context)
         .load(xxx)
         .into(this)
}

bgImageView?.let { 
    Glide.with(context)
         .load(xxx)
         .into(it)
}
```

The style guide also describes [intended uses](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#using-scope-functions-applywithrunalsolet) of the `with`, `also`, and `run` functions.